# UIPopover crashing when rotated

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a universal app that displays buttons inside an actionsheet.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:[dataObj.preferences objectForKey:@"appts_name"], @"Reserve", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

On an iPad that automatically gets changed to a `UIPopoverController`. This displays and acts fine, however if I have the above popover being displayed and change orientation on the iPad then tap one of the buttons, it crashes in that buttons method where I am wanting to display another popover, saying that

```
-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.
```

If I do not rotate the iPad and just tap a button it executes the same code just fine.

```
UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addItemView];
popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navBar];
if (viewPopover) {
    if (self.view.window != nil) {
        CLS_LOG(@"Rect: %@ - View: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rectPopover), viewPopover);
        [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:rectPopover inView:viewPopover permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
} else {
    // We should NEVER get here but just incase. I don't want the app to crash.
    CLS_LOG(@"No viewPopover or rectPopover - %@ - %@", viewPopover, NSStringFromCGRect(rectPopover));
}
```

Log from the CLS_LOG

```
-[AppointmentViewController showAppointmentAdd] line 148 $ Rect: {{341.333, 592}, {1, 1}} - View: <UIScrollView: 0xc8c5d40; frame = (1044 0; 768 872); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xc8c7780>; contentOffset: {-0, 188}>
```

`rectPopover` and `viewPopover` are legit. Why is the popOver crashing saying it isn't in a window, but only when I rotate the device?

EDIT:
I found out it is being caused because after orientation change, I am reloading the view to account for the new sizes. It seems this takes precedence in the window. It also only seems to affect the UIActionSheet.

Comment: what are rectPopover and viewPopover? How do you know that they are legit?

Comment: @Abizern I added the log from them.

Comment: As you can see - rectPopover is not legit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried tried redisplaying the popover after rotation?

You know when the rotation is occurring (`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`), and then you can redisplay the popover controller according to it's new anchor point.

Comment: I am closing the UIAction in willRotate and reopening it in didRotate and it still is crashing even after I refresh the view that I need to be resized.

Comment: You led me in the right direction. It turns out in my reloadViews, I was removing from super the viewPopover.